# Parsing command output and build bash key-values

Tags: bash, shell, dictionary, awk

I have a command which gives output as following

```
2 physical slots found:   
slot 1:
     Cstatus: present
     Sstatus: active
     apps: 0   
slot 2:
     Cstatus: present
     Sstatus: inactive
     apps: 0
```

I want to build Key-value pair  in *bash* script from this output like *slot1[Cstatus]* as "*present*" , *slot2[Sstatus]* as "*inactive*".
Any pointers will be very helpful.

I  tried this  which gives status for each slot entry but i want  a better solution

```
slot1_status=$(awk '/slot 1:/ {  for(i=1; i<3; i++) { getline;  if(match($0, /Sstatus:/)) {print $3}}}' slot_status.txt)
```

Thanks in  advance,
prap4learn

Comment: `bash` isn't the best language for this. It doesn't have 2-dimensional arrays, and creating arrays with dynamic variable names is not easy.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Provide a sample output, matching the provided input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample `awk` solution:

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {       # pre process initial variable
  FS = ":";     # set field separator to "|"
}
/slot/ {  # for  each line having  "slot"
  currentSlot = $1;
}
!/slot/ { # for  each line not having "slot"
  sub("^[ ]+", "", $1); # trim spaces on 1st field
  gsub("[ ]+", "", $2); # trim spaces on 2nd field
  print currentSlot "[" $1 "] as \"" $2"\""; # output key/value pair

}
```

#### running the `script.awk`

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

#### oneliner `awk` command

```
awk -F":" '/slot/{s=$1}!/slot/{sub("^[ ]+","",$1);gsub("[ ]+","",$2);print s"["$1"] as \""$2"\""}' input.txt
```

#### input.txt

```
2 physical slots found:   
slot 1:
     Cstatus: present
     Sstatus: active
     apps: 0   
slot 2:
     Cstatus: present
     Sstatus: inactive
     apps: 0
```

#### output

```
slot 1[Cstatus] as "present"
slot 1[Sstatus] as "active"
slot 1[apps] as "0"
slot 2[Cstatus] as "present"
slot 2[Sstatus] as "inactive"
slot 2[apps] as "0"
```

Comment: Maybe add explanation of the output syntax or grammar (python?)

Comment: @lea Gris this is not `python` it is `awk`. All `print` values are concatenated, constant strings  are quoted with `"`

Comment: Thanks will try this out

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works with Bash version 4.3 or above with support for:

- `declare -n var` nameref variables
- `declare -A var` associative arrays

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Require Bash version 4.3+ for nameref and associative arrays

# Declare associative arrays to capture key value pairs
declare -A slot1=() slot2=()

# Declare a nameref variable that will control in which array to insert
# captured key value pairs
declare -n array_ref=_

# Iterate reading lines of the file
while IFS= read -r line
do
  # Regex match and capture groups or skip line if no match
  [[ $line =~ ^([[:space:]]*)(.*):[[:space:]]*(.*)$ ]] || continue

  # Uncomment to debug Regex
  # typeset -p BASH_REMATCH

  # If first captured group is empty (no space)
  if [ -z "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" ]; then
    case ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} in
      'slot 1')
        # Switch the nameref variable to the slot1 associative array
        declare -n array_ref=slot1
        continue
        ;;
      'slot 2')
        # Switch the nameref variable to the slot2 associative array
        declare -n array_ref=slot2
        continue
        ;;
      *)
        # An unknown array name to ignore
        declare -n array_ref=_
        continue
        ;;
      esac
    else
      # First captured group contains spaces, so capture key values
      k=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
      v=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

      # Insert key value pair into the associative array pointed by array_ref
      # shellcheck disable=SC2034 # array_ref is used in assignment
      array_ref["$k"]=$v
    fi
done

# shellcheck disable=SC2034 # debug print
typeset -p slot1 slot2
```

Example of result from the script above

```sh
declare -A slot1=([Cstatus]="present" [apps]="0" [Sstatus]="active" )
declare -A slot2=([Cstatus]="present" [apps]="0" [Sstatus]="inactive" )
```

Comment: Thanks will try this out